# Very slow server and straight entries in error.log

Tags: security, hacking

I am running ubuntu `16.04` and suddenly over the last 2 days my server is basically at a stand still, I have upgraded everything and cleaned my error.log.

I rebooted the server and about about 5mins it again came to a standstill. Checking the processes nothing is over 10% cpu.

WHen checking the error log the below entries are the only things I can see that are odd to me.

```
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:50.398619 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/9678.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:50.509673 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/wc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:50.630470 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/xx.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:50.827904 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/s.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:51.002760 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/w.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:51.179510 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/sheep.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:51.411913 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/qaq.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:51.649432 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/db.init.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:51.967375 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/db_session.init.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:52.160257 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/db__.init.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:52.536444 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/wp-admins.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:52.765769 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/m.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:53.076742 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/099.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:53.329621 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/_404.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:53.588267 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/Alarg53.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:53.823077 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/lapan.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:53.918564 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/p34ky1337.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:54.081972 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/pk1914.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:54.179365 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/sllolx.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:54.290338 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/Skri.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:54.529489 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/db_dataml.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:54.755711 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/db_desql.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:54.850979 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/mx.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.118621 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/wshell.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.368692 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/xshell.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.470548 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/qq.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.570334 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/conflg.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.670565 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/conflg.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.786180 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/lindex.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.907402 2019] [:error] [pid 8974] [client 45.113.70.238:41364] script '/var/www/files/phpstudy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 12 13:21:55.993093 2019] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 8702] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

Comment: Someone's scanning your server for vulnerabilities. This'll happen many times a day to a public server. Consider something like `fail2ban` to block IPs after a certain number of these sorts of requests. (and make sure if you've got any third-party stuff installed like WordPress, Drupal, etc. that you be sure to keep it updated)

Comment: Yep, fail2ban would knock this out.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will set this up tomorrow